# Python newbie here-Python iterations

Tags: python, string, iteration

Python newbie here- could you please explain the following

```
greeting = 'Hello!' 
count = 0  
for letter in greeting:
     count += 1   
  if count % 2 == 0: 
        print(letter) 
    print(letter) 
 print('done')
```

Comment: There are tutorials for that.

Comment: That code won't run because it's riddled with indentation errors. Correct indentation is _vital_ in Python.

Comment: Try to correct your indentation first. Save your program into hello.py, then run python hello.py to check your result. After that you could play it around with your code to understand its behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

```
greeting = 'Hello!' <-- set greeting variable.
count = 0  <-- set count variable.
for letter in greeting: <-- this loop will loop six times because greeting contains of six character.
     count += 1  <-- each times of loop will increase value of count by one.
  if count % 2 == 0: <-- this line will print a index of character that % 2 = 0 (eg. 2%2 = 0, 4%2 = 0, ...)
        print(letter) 
    print(letter) <-- this line will print any index of character of greeting. (ps. this line will error because indentation errors.)
 print('done') <-- print 'done'.
```

> So the result will be like this:

H 
 e 
 e 
 l 
 l 
 l 
 o 
 ! 
 ! 
 done

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding the indentation error, I am explaining what your code does.

In your program, you have initialized a variable named greeting with value "Hello!" and also a count with value 0.

greeting = 'Hello!' 
count = 0

Thereafter a for loop us used which loop through the greeting i.e. till the end of each word **Hello!**. However, if you wanted to check it by yourself you can print the letter.

for letter in greeting:
     print(letter)

Now coming to your problem where you've also incremented the value of count by 1 where the value increases by 1 on each loop execution.

Then you have a condition to check whether the number is even or not **count % 2 == 0** followed by the print statement which executes upon the success of condition. This means the letter at the even position will only get printed.

That is what your program does.

Answer (score 0):

```
greeting = 'Hello!' <-- set greeting variable.
count = 0  <-- set count variable.
for letter in greeting: <-- this loop will loop six times because greeting contains of six character.
     count += 1  <-- each times of loop will increase value of count by one.
     if count % 2 == 0: <-- this line will print a index of character that % 2 = 0 (eg. 2%2 = 0, 4%2 = 0, ...)
        print(letter) 
    print(letter) <-- this line will print any index of character of greeting. (ps. this line will error because indentation errors.)
print('done') <-- print 'done'.
```

[image: Output]